# How to write a stored procedure to return a count of events grouped by 'X' week blocks?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, grouping

I have a table that records market interactions by employees with customers. Relevant fields would be customerid, date and customer type.

I want to be able to get a count of interactions by 5 week blocks going back as far as the between dates that would be submitted by the user and discriminate by customer type a,b,c.

I want to be able to take the returned data and create an a,b and c series with counts of market interactions grouped by 5 week blocks.

Something like:

```
 double[] byValues = { 14, 16, 18, 19, 15, 18, 19, 14, 15 };

 string[] bxValues = { "50", "45", "40", "35", "30", "25", "20", "15", "10" };
```

which might be the A-Series. Once I have my A, B and C series i can then feed them into a stackedchart graph.

I would also like the user to be able to adjust X=5 from 1 to 20 so it would be nice to have that variable as dynamic. Any pointers or urls would be appreciated.

My initial thoughts were to query once and create a temp table with an additional field that was populated by an if statement with some math in it that calculated the block rank of the record according to its date. Then i could requery that with a grouping count for the other criteria. But Im really not sure what the most performant way of getting that first step done, is. It seems like the kind of thing i could get badly wrong perhaps by orders of magnitude.

UPDATE:

This is what I have done and it works. Its actually quite simple. There are some literals in there which I can easily convert to parameters.

```
SELECT  mi1.[CAQ] AS CAQ, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(d, mi1.IDate, CONVERT(datetime, '11/07/2010', 103))/5) AS X_AXISBLOCK 
INTO #myTempTable
FROM [ql10_crm].[MarketInteraction] mi1 INNER JOIN [ql10_crm].[TerritoryCustomer] 
ON mi1.[CustomerId] =[ql10_crm].[TerritoryCustomer].[CustomerId] 
WHERE mi1.[CAQ] IN(1,2,4) AND 
[ql10_crm].[TerritoryCustomer].[TerritoryId] IN(19) AND (mi1.[IDate] BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '18/06/2009', 103) AND  CONVERT(datetime, '11/07/2010', 103));

SELECT CAQ, X_AXISBLOCK , COUNT([CAQ])
FROM #myTempTable
GROUP BY CAQ, X_AXISBLOCK 
ORDER BY CAQ, X_AXISBLOCK;
```

Not sure how performant or flexible it is in comparision to the answers. Will have to test.

This is my output (CAQ, X_AXISBLOCK , COUNT) Where a CAQ of 1=A, 2=B, 4=C:

```
2 0 2
2 1 6
2 6 2
4 0 3
4 1 5
4 6 4
```

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you on? And what if the customer enters a 9 week period? would that be the first block 4 weeks and second block five or vice-versa? Or can they only enter exact multiples of 5 weeks?

Comment: @Martin Smith Sql Server 2005 > 2008

Comment: @Martin Smith Hi, they can enter any number between 1 and X. At this point X is abitrary.It seems like it should have an upper limit otherwise the graphs will simply have one datapoint as the data only goes back 3 years thus far. But whatever x is the remainder would be placed in the last (oldest) block. The first block would always be a complete block if the age of the data (in weeks) exceeded X.

Comment: @rism - So they don't enter an explicit date? They just enter an int and then you want it counting back in X week increments from current date?

Comment: @Martin Smith The would supply the "from" and "to" dates and they could alter the value of X. X basically allows them to refine the level of detail they see in the graph whereby big values reduce details i.e. bigger groups, fewer datapoints. So X is adjusts the fidelity of the graph.

Comment: @Martin Smith Or more simply X divides the date range into [n] blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You've lost me a bit with the talk of temp tables and block ranks but won't this do what you need?

```
DECLARE @X INT
SET @X =5

DECLARE @endDate DATETIME
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME

SET @endDate = '2010-07-18'
SET @startDate = '2009-07-18'

DECLARE @EndDateDays INT
SET @EndDateDays = CAST(@endDate AS INT);



WITH MarketInteractions AS
(
SELECT 1 AS customerid, CAST('2010-07-18' AS DATETIME) AS [DATE], 'a' AS CustomerType
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS customerid, CAST('2010-06-18' AS DATETIME) AS [DATE], 'b' AS CustomerType
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS customerid, CAST('2010-05-18' AS DATETIME) AS [DATE], 'a' AS CustomerType

),
MarketInteractions2 AS 
(
SELECT 1+ ((CAST(@endDate - [DATE] AS INT)) / (@X * 7)) AS Period, customerid, CustomerType
FROM MarketInteractions
WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND CustomerType IN ('a','b','c')
)

/* Possibly with a join on a numbers table to get periods with zero interactions if 
 that is possible*/

SELECT 
Period, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN CustomerType = 'a' THEN 1 END) AS a,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CustomerType = 'b' THEN 1 END) AS b,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CustomerType = 'c' THEN 1 END) AS c
FROM MarketInteractions2
GROUP BY Period,  CustomerType
```

Comment: Yes. I really like the bit about getting zero interactions. I was going to do this in code, a bit rough but with the ordering very easily done. I will test in the morning. Thanks very much.

Comment: I did just have a quick run of it and I got quite different output from my output. All the interaction counts are = 1 and i only got 3 records back for the same time span.

Comment: @rism - I take it you did remove my demo table in the CTE and replaced it with something appropriate?

Comment: Hi, i didnt know what a CTE is until i just googled it right now which probably explains why i cant see one in what you've written. More reading. This is great. Im going to learn something here.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but it seems to me like you might be able to do this in pure SQL (usually preferable), rather than resorting to a stored procedure.

Have a look at the analytical functions available to you [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx). These have been well supported in Oracle for a long time now, but they are finding their way into SQL Server now.

By way of example, you would be looking at something like this (by no means a complete solution - just a pointer really):

```
SELECT a.custid,
       a.weekblock,
       COUNT(a.custid) OVER (PARTITION BY a.weekblock, a.custid)
  FROM (SELECT x.custid, DATEPART(wk, x.date) / 5 AS weekblock
          FROM market x) a
```

If you provide more information about your table structure, a better solution could probably be derived.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the use of the partition keyword tomorrow. Your SQL looks nicely simplified.

Comment: Thanks. Best of luck. Don't forget to let us know how it works out.